# Gifting subscription Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe for a X dollar per month service. I'd like to provide the ability for a user to gift another user a Z months.

The nice thing about stripe is it automatically notifies me when a subscription ends (due to billing/end of a subscription, etc). I don't store the "expiration" in my database.

However, for gifting the approach, I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm using Payment Links and trying to manually create a subscription on the user that is being gifted the service (this way I can kind of keep the subscription architecture that exists).

```
subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: stripeCustomer.id,
      items: [{ price: priceId, quantity }],
    });
```

However, I get an error - because the priceId that I'm using is not a recurring one but a one time payment. I.e. The gifter can choose to pay for 2 months to gift to someone.

```
 API Handler Error Caught The price specified is set to `type=one_time` but this field only accepts prices with `type=recurring`
```

What is the best approach here? One hacky idea I had was to create a parallel price ID that is recurring and use that and then figure out a way to set an expiration date for 30d in the future, but it just seems hacky... Is there a better way with Payment links?

Comment: what would you like to happen after that two months? e.g. Simply cancel the subscription?

Comment: correct, unless the user decides to subscribe themselves

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Subscription requires a recurring Price. You cannot use a one-time Price.

You can consider creating a Subscription with either a $0 recurring Price, or use a trial period ([trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-trial_end) or [trial_period_days](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_period_days)
). Subsequently, either use [cancel_at](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at) or [cancel_at_period_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) to cancel the Subscription after a period of time.

In case you haven't seen this yet,  you can use test clocks to mimic the passing of time : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks

Comment: Do you know if a payment method is required for this to work?

Comment: no, a Subscription doesn't require a PaymentMethod to be created if the first invoice is $0